# Stuck in tty after fsck error on boot

Tags: ubuntu, tty, fsck

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on my laptop.

After starting the laptop, I got `/dev/sda8: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY`

According to this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually) I am fixing the error with `fsck -f /dev/sda8 -y` but after rebooting, the system boots in tty and stuck there.

What I have tried:

**startx** gives the `Fatal server error: Could not create lock file in /temp/.tX0-lock`

**init6** comes back to fsck error

**Reboot** also comes back to the fsck error

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> does nothing

Can sombody help me solve the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the boot sequence?

Comment: You can view with this [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/18Jv8p4yjupzLji2A)

Comment: no, we mean the boot sequence after you hit "enter" there - the part where you see the actual error.  because it LOOKS like you need to manually run `fsck` on your device from a live environment to repair any inconsistencies in the ext partition

Comment: Sorry! My bad! [Here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/MnWVf1S4ubkKUi24A) is the error and steps that I took. I do fix fsck but after rebooting, it goes to tty and I can't get out of there.

Answer (score 0):

If your server boot into a tty directly, and if `init 5` didn't work for you, there are two possibilities:

1. The desktop package is not installed or broken.
2. You didn't setup your runlevel properly.

You can install ubuntu desktop by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then make sure this is the default "runlevel", you can use:

```
sudo systemctl enable multi-user.target
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Reboot your server.